# Table break if table it's bigger than div container when print

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal project and I need to create a print template for budgets and I already have it, but I have a problem with the table break because I can not make the break.
I've tried it in many ways and nothing.

what I want to do is when the table is larger than its container, it does a table break and continues to the next page.

my structure:

```
<div class="sheet-paper">
 <div class="sheet-report">
  <div class="page-header">
    <!-- All header things -->
  </div>

  <div class="page-report">
   <table class="table table-striped" table style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr class="active">
            <th class="text-center text-primary" style="font-size: 11px; width:15%">Item nº</th>
            <th class="text-center text-primary" style="font-size: 11px; width:37%">Descrição</th>
            <th class="text-center text-primary" style="font-size: 11px; width:16%">Preço Unit. </th>
            <th class="text-center text-primary" style="font-size: 11px; width:16%">Quantidade </th>
            <th class="text-center text-primary" style="font-size: 11px; width:16%">Preço </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php for($i=0; $i< (count($results) - 1); $i++){?>
            <tr class="page-break">
                <td class="text-left" style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo $results[$i]['item_n']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo $results[$i]['description']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right" style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo number_format($results[$i]['unit_price'], 2); ?>€</td>
                <td class="text-right" style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo number_format($results[$i]['qty'], 0); ?></td>
                <td class="text-right" style="font-size: 10px;"><?php echo number_format($results[$i]['price'], 2); ?>€<span class="invisible">)</span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-footer">
   <!-- All footer things -->
  </div>
</div>



@media print {
 .page-header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 19.5cm;
 top: -25px;
 }
.page-report {
 position: fixed;
 top: 8.3cm;
 width: 19.5cm;
 height: 12.7cm;
}
.page-footer {
 position: fixed;
 width: 19.5cm;
 bottom: 0;
 page-break-before: auto;
}
.btn-report {
 display: none;
}
table tr.page-break {
 page-break-after: auto;
 max-height: 8cm
}
table {
 page-break-inside: auto
}
}
```

[image: This is what's happening.]

Comment: What happens when you remove all the `position: fixed;`?

Comment: almost the same thing, but the table instead of getting behind the footer, gets ahead!!!